# ¿Cómo puedo pausar un audio al momento de reproducir otro en html?

Tags: html, html5, audio

```css
.pod{
 margin: 25px;
 background: #ededed;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.pod audio{
 margin: 10px;
 width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pod">
 <audio src="sound/happy.mp3" controls="controls" preload="preload"></audio>
 <audio src="sound/sad.mp3" controls="controls" preload="preload"></audio>
</div>
```

Tengo estas lineas de código y necesito que al momento de reproducir una se pause la otra en caso de que esta se esté reproduciendo. Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Que has intentado ? no solo busques que te hagan el trabajo, agrega el código que has intentado o errores que te estén deteniendo en el desarrollo , este tipos de preguntas son de baja calidad, y puedes obtener votos negativos.

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO Muchísimas gracias por la sugerencia, la tendré en cuenta para futuras preguntas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te dejo una solucion en jQery, solo tenes que agregar esta funcion en un JS aparte, o en la etiqueta `script` como lo hago en el ejemplo mas abajo.

```
  // CUANDO SE DÉ PLAY EN CUALQUIER ELEMENTO CON LA ETIQUETA AUDIO
$("audio").on("play", function() {  
  // A TODOS LOS DEMAS AUDIOS QUE NO SEAN EL QUE SE PUSO EN PLAY      
$("audio").not(this).each(function(index, audio) {
        // LO PAUSO
        audio.pause();
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="pod">
 <audio src="https://ia800207.us.archive.org/29/items/MLKDream/MLKDream_64kb.mp3" controls="controls" preload="preload"></audio>
 <audio src="https://ia800207.us.archive.org/29/items/MLKDream/MLKDream_64kb.mp3" controls="controls" preload="preload"></audio>
</div>

<script>
$("audio").on("play", function() {
    $("audio").not(this).each(function(index, audio) {
        audio.pause();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias compañero, estoy trabajando en una sección podcast y me topé con el problema que los audios se mezclaban.
De antemano agradezco un montón tu ayuda.